# RegEx getting lookaheads to work for each separate word in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm trying to create a regex to pull a **single** reference number from a string that consists of multiple words.

A reference number is any uppercase alpha-numeric word with 6 or more characters. i.e. GAF7887979, 897979, etc.

So far i'm using the following to capture these references: `[A-Z\d-]{6,}` in combination with a positive look-ahead to ensure at least a single digit in the match: `(?=.*\d)`.

However I need to filter out a particular formatted date which looks like the following: `19MAR19` to do this i'm using a negative look-ahead: `(?!\d{2}[A-Z]{3}1\d)` which seems to work fine.

The final regex is: `(?!\d{2}[A-Z]{3}1\d)(?=.*\d)[A-Z\d-]{6,}`

So this all works fine and dandy for a single word, but in a string with multiple words the look-ahead's don't seem to be working for each word, but instead for the whole string (understandable), so everything ends up matching if there is at least one digit in the string :(

Is there anyway to get the look-ahead's to re-apply to each new word in the regex?

Example:

[image: Example regex at work]

Comment: [Link to regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/1eG3aK/1)

Comment: you don't want to allow 17MAR1 ?

Comment: You only have to prepend a word boundary `\b` to it.

Comment: Anything with the format `DDMMMYY` so `\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}` but we can be more precise with the year as all these dates are within the last couple of years so the first digit will always be `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point here is to restrict `.` inside the lookahead. Note that `.` matches any character but line break characters. The lookahead `(?=.*\d)` returns *true* if there is a digit after **any** 0+ chars other than line break chars, thus, all the [words before a valid match are also matched](https://regex101.com/r/1eG3aK/3).

Since you only match uppercase letters and digits, use `[A-Z\d]*` instead of `.*`.

You also need word boundaries to make sure whole words are matched.

Use

```
\b(?!\d{2}[A-Z]{3}1\d)(?=[A-Z\d]*\d\b)[A-Z\d-]{6,}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8YDV6R/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(?!\d{2}[A-Z]{3}1\d)` -  no 2 digits, 3 uppercase ASCII letters, `1` and a digit right after the word boundary
- `(?=[A-Z\d]*\d\b)` - there must be any 0+ uppercase letters or/and digits and a digit followed with a word boundary
- `[A-Z\d-]{6,}` - six or more digits/letters/`-`
- `\b` - followed with a word boundary.

Comment: Oh wow, you're a beast. Thank you very much! Just waiting for the timer to mark this as accepted :D

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, why is HOSTON getting matched in https://regex101.com/r/1eG3aK/2

Comment: @marvel308 Yes, that is OP original regex. It matches `HOSTON` before `DDAFES123` on the same line because `(?=.*\d)` lookahead returns *true*.

Comment: how come HOSTON in the first line wasn't matched, but it matched whenever their was another valid match along with it ? like in the 2nd line, OK so [^\s]* would've also worked

Comment: @marvel308: `.` matches any char but line break chars. The lookahead `(?=.*\d)` returns *true* if there is a digit after *any* 0+ chars other than line break chars.